# Ruby on rails finding unique entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to populate a select menu with options from my database.  There are many copies of the same entree, and because of that I get a drop down menu that have the same name again and again.  I want to just get entries from my table so i have one of each possibility on it.

I have tried looking around for different ways to call information from the database, including that fact that Conditions can be applied to the call, unfortunately I must not have found the right one.  also I found that

```
 @products.uniq(:brand)
```

returned the full list, so I am probably using that wrong also.  If I cannot do it in a single call, what would I need to do to get the same result.

Comment: Difficult to tell, but `Products.select(:brand).uniq`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure brand should be a separate model in here. Then you'd just do Brand.all.map(&:name) or Brand.all.pluck(:name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly the desired outcome. Are you looking for an array of values from the `products.brand` column where no entry is repeated? If so, you can do the following:

`Product.uniq.pluck(:brand)`

If you need to add extra conditions it's easy enough to do, you can just add a `where(:foo => :bar)` (but you need to add it before the `pluck` call).

Comment: Note that `pluck` requires Rails 3.2, but it's definitely the best choice (it's fallen out of my common use because I primarily maintain a huge Rails 3.0 app :|)